# Posting JSON with file content on Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, attachment

Does anyone know how to post a JSON to a Rails server with a file attached? Would the content be base64 encoded? Multipart? I honestly have no idea and havent really found anything here to help. Idea is to have a client posting a JSON to a rails API with the file attached, as well as having the Rails (with paperclip would be perfect) getting the JSON and saving the file properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: What tools are you using? Where are you in the process? Have you gotten a file to post correctly? Are you using any gems? If not, have you looked at [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)? For future reference, try using [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What code have you written? By showing what you've written we can modify it, rather than write something from scratch, reinventing your wheel, and forcing you to heavily modify what you've done just to shoehorn it in.

Comment: What specifically have you researched so far?

Comment: I am starting to write the code after a few examples I've seen. Yes I am planing to use paperclip, and maybe rest-client (this one only after I learn how to do without it). So basically I'd like to do a simple http-client post request, with ruby, to my rails server which already has paperclip, and make it work. I have researched so far things like "posting multipart on json" and alike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem. First I created a rake task to upload the file within the json content:

```
desc "Tests JSON uploads with attached files on multipart formats"
task :picture => :environment do
    file = File.open(Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', 'photo.jpg'))

    data = {title: "Something", description: "Else", file_content: Base64.encode64(file.read)}.to_json
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/users.json", {"Content-Type" => "application/json", 'Accept' => '*/*'})
    req.body = data

    response = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", "3000").start {|http| http.request(req) }
    puts response.body
  end
```

And then got this on the controller/model of my rails app, like this:

```
params[:user] = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

    has_attached_file :picture, formats: {medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100#100"}


    def file_content=(c)
      filename = "#{Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub('.', '_')}.jpg"
      File.open("/tmp/#{filename}", 'wb') {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(c).strip) }
      self.picture = File.open("/tmp/#{filename}", 'r')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a data serializing format. There is no standard pattern for uploading data or files as data in the serialized object. JSON has expectations that the data fields will be basic objects so you probably want to use Base64 encoding of the file to turn it into a string.

You are free to define your structure however you want, and processing it is your responsibility.